# Conditionally override css in Style tag

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Assuming I am using a plugin that generates `html` at runtime where I cannot edit the `CSS` or `JS` code, leaving me with the only option of overriding certain `CSS` in particular classes. For instance, in such case I'd often do:

```
.video-player{
   max-height: 500px !important;
}
```

In case such styling must be handled conditionally based on the props passes to the component, for instance:

```
<videoPlayer :goSmall="anotherColumn != null"></videoPlayer>
```

since the `CSS` in the `videoPlayer` components must go in the `Style` tag:

```
<style scoped>
   .video-player{
       max-height: 500px !important;
   }
</style>
```

how can I render it conditionally?

It is such a bad idea to append it to the DOM using lifecyle hooks, so please do not suggest anything like that.

Comment: Whats wrong with dynamically applying CSS using lifecycle hooks?,
I'm assuming you need to treat videoPlayer Component as a black-box

Comment: @AbhishekGupta: The issue with that is, its impact covers the whole dom, and I have to take care of the removal too. One way is to traditionally use JQuery to add the style to a particular div, but I want to know about a Vue solution.

Answer (score 0):

Why not apply a specific class to the component instead of passing a prop?

```
<videoPlayer :class="{ small: anotherColumn != null }"></videoPlayer>
```

And the css

```
<style scoped>
.video-player.small {
   max-height: 500px !important;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score -2):

If you are not okay with dynamically applying CSS using lifecycle hooks. You can always box your components. Make two components for your `videoPlayer`, we'll call them `videoPlayerOriginal` and `videoPlayerSmall`.

```
//videoPlayerOriginal.vue
<videoPlayer></videoPlayer>
```

Add your css in `videoPlayerSmall.vue`

```
//videoPlayerOriginal.vue
<videoPlayer></videoPlayer>

<style scoped>
 .video-player{
    max-height: 500px !important;
  }
</style>
```

Now render either one of them conditionally.

Comment: This is such a terrible solution as it brings redundant code and complicates the design. I'm after neat solutions.

Comment: Ok, but if you really don't want to dynamically change CSS and can't change videoPlayer component, then I am just as curious about this. Generally, integrating third party plugins requires stepping the framework aside.

Comment: @Arrrr So, since we don't have "better" answer here. Mind re-considering the downvotes? Since it still does solve the problem.